# HW Raid controller error

Tags: redhat, hardware-raid, 3ware

On one of my old servers when i was randomly checking for system messages /var/log/messages in this Redhat case. I came across this message

```
Mar  9 12:11:46 app-prod kernel: 3w-9xxx: scsi0: ERROR: (0x03:0x0101): Invalid command opcode:opcode=0x85.
Mar  9 12:11:46 app-db-prod kernel: 3w-9xxx: scsi0: ERROR: (0x03:0x0101): Invalid command opcode:opcode=0x85.
```

I need to know whether this is critical error or can be ignore.

Raid Controller model is = 9650SE-4LPML (3ware)
OS = Redhat 6.4 x64

Comment: What about the 3ware documentation ? From my 3ware experience warning is a warning and error is critical... But both of them must be processed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this thread (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/618542):

> I found an answer to the ERROR: (0x03:0x0101): Invalid command opcode:opcode=0x85 problem:
>
> http://kb.lsi.com/Print16532.aspx :
> "This error can be safely ignored."

What is happening is that the kernel is sending a scsi code 0x85 (which from http://www.t10.org/lists/op-num.htm is 85  ATA PASS-THROUGH(16). This is presumably to check something on the disk itself (temp or some other reported value) and the card/drive is not able to respond appropriately.

If you are having other errors with the drives, then address those, but if this is the only message you see and everything appears fine otherwise, feel free to ignore.

Comment: Yes dear i found it on other website which now i forgot but i will keep this one as reference . Thanks and have a very nice day