# Supress 3Ware warnings in syslog

Tags: regex, syslog, rsyslog, 3ware, slackware

I'm trying to suppress the following warnings in my syslog:

```
Oct 13 04:43:33 Winston kernel: 3w-sas: scsi1: ERROR: (0x03:0x0101): Invalid command opcode:opcode=0x85.
Oct 13 04:43:33 Winston kernel: md: do_drive_cmd: disk0: ATA_OP e0 ioctl error: -22
Oct 13 04:43:33 Winston kernel: mdcmd (839855): spindown 1
Oct 13 04:43:33 Winston kernel: 3w-sas: scsi1: ERROR: (0x03:0x0101): Invalid command opcode:opcode=0x85.
Oct 13 04:43:33 Winston kernel: md: do_drive_cmd: disk1: ATA_OP e0 ioctl error: -22
Oct 13 04:43:34 Winston kernel: mdcmd (839856): spindown 0
Oct 13 04:43:34 Winston kernel: 3w-sas: scsi1: ERROR: (0x03:0x0101): Invalid command opcode:opcode=0x85.
Oct 13 04:43:34 Winston kernel: md: do_drive_cmd: disk0: ATA_OP e0 ioctl error: -22
Oct 13 04:43:34 Winston kernel: mdcmd (839857): spindown 1
```

From what i understand from [this post on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/674043/hw-raid-controller-error), these messages can savely be ignored. My drives work fine, it just seems that my raid-controller cannot handle specific commands that the OS is trying to get.

I'm running Unraid (Slackware), so my syslog gets written by `rsyslog.d`. I edited the following file to ignore specific messages without luck: `/etc/rsyslog.d/01-blocklist.conf`.

Variations of what i tried:

```
:msg,contains,"error: mdcmd, 2640: Invalid argument (22): write" ~
:msg,regex,"md: do_drive_cmd: disk\d ATA_OP e0 ioctl error: -22" ~
:msg,regex,"mdcmd (\d+): spindown \d" ~

:msg,contains,"3w-sas: scsi5: ERROR: (0x03:0x0101)" ~
:msg,contains,"Winston kernel: 3w-sas: scsi1: ERROR" ~
:msg,contains,"kernel: 3w-sas: scsi1: ERROR" ~
```

Could anyone help me what i'm doing wrong, either with the `contains` command and/or the `regex` ones?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Winston kernel:" string is not part of the `msg` property, which usually begins with the space after the ":".

The `regex` operation uses Posix BRE (basic regular expressions), so `\d` does not exist;  instead try `[0-9]`. Also, `+` does not exist, and you will need `*`.  Alternatively, if supported, you can use the extended regex operation: `ereregex`; you will then have `+`, but you need `\(\)` for literal parentheses.

Also, `~` is very old deprecated syntax so unless you have a very old rsyslog you should use `stop` instead (though `~` should still work).

Comment: thanks. i didn't get it completely as i wanted, but overall i was able to remove all warnings/errors i intended to. THE BRE/ERE tip was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The e0 command is STANDBY IMMEDIATE.  I think that is being sent by power management to put the drive to sleep after a period of inactivity.  Turning that off should get rid of the cause of the error, rather than just mask the logging.